# Attempting to pass argument from one function to another

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementById("QuantityList").value;
  return a;
}

function myFunction2(a) {
  var b = a * 4.99;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = b;
  return b;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="QuantityList"> 
      <option value="0">0 </option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<td>
  <p id="demo"> </p>
</td>
```

Knowing that it is not typically possible to return two values from a single JS function, I thought I would use one function to perform one task, then pass the value of that function to another function within the code.

I want to be able to find the number of items that has been selected from the drop down menu and attempted to do this in my myFunction function.

I then tried to pass the value of the myFunction function to the myFunction2 function....but I am getting zero output....

Comment: You'd need to pass the result of one function to the other. Of course, you can return two values from a single function; just use an array or an object, like `return { a: a, b: b };`.

Comment: I see no call to myFunction2

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but you need to pick up a good book on the basics of programming - you're misunderstanding some fundamentals. Like you're never actually capturing the result of calling the function. And just calling an input `a` doesnt automatically get the result of the other function. Not to mention the concept of debugging your code..

Answer (score 0):

You can easily return two (or more) values at once by creating an object with properties, like this:

```js
function fn() {
  var x = { value1 : "v1", value2 : "v2" };
  return x;
}

var result = fn();

console.log(result.value1);
console.log(result.value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding my comment about needing to get a grip of the fundamentals of programming, I will give you a solution below to shove you along. You need to make sure you have a grip on some of the basics like how to pass values around, how to debug your program etc.

---

There are a few things wrong with your code

1. Your method names are terrible - method names should describe what it is they're doing.
2. You never actually call `myFunction2`, and you therefore never pass it a value for `a` (This doesnt happen automagically just because you named another (private) variable `a`)

See the below:

```js
function getQualtityValue() {
  var a = document.getElementById("QuantityList").value;
  return a;
}

function executeDemo(a) {
  var b = a * 4.99;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = b;
  return b; // theres no need to return this. It does no harm so I left it.
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="QuantityList"> 
      <option value="0">0 </option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br>
<button type="button" onclick="executeDemo(getQualtityValue())">Try it</button>
<td>
  <p id="demo"> </p>
</td>
```